# Socket communication between PC and Moble

Tags: android, android-networking

I am trying to make communication between my mobile and my PC. I use socket to do this.
The server in mobile side start successfully and it show there is a request coming from my PC's browser, it shows me the request is from IP 192.168.1.100 which is my PC's LAN IP, it's correct. However, from mobile it cannot send a message back to PC. Here is the sample code.

Response status:

```
Socket socket = client;
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
m_activityMain.handler.sendMessage(
       m_activityMain.handler.obtainMessage(1,socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()));

String response = "";
response += "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
response += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
response += "\r\n";
out.write(response.getBytes());
out.write(new Boolean(this.isAlive()).toString().getBytes());// output status
Thread.sleep (1000);
out.flush();
out.close();
reader.close();
```

In browser, it always shows connection stop error and cannot display this message, I don't know why?

Comment: Maybe it’s because you close the connection? Do you listen for incoming data?

Comment: yes. It shows the HTTP request information from browser.